# Angular JS - Ui-select js file not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

Its been a day since i have stuck in this problem. I have install `ui-select` through `bower` and its installed successfully.  The css file is loading correctly but the javascript file is not loading in the network call, but I can clearly see the file in view page source.

Thats why i get this error.

```
    Failed to instantiate module BlurAdmin due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.select due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.select' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here is my `app.js`

```
    'use strict';//NOSONAR


(function () {
    angular.module('BlurAdmin', [
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'ngAnimate',
        'rzModule',
        'angular-confirm',
        'ngSegment',
        'ngFileUpload',
        'multipleDatePickerAdvanced',
        'multipleDatePicker',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.sortable',
        'ui.router',
        'ui.select',
        'infinite-scroll',
        'ngSanitize',
        'toastr',
        'smart-table',
        "xeditable",
        'ui.slimscroll',
        'ngJsTree',
        'angular-progress-button-styles',
        'jsonFormatter',
        'angularPromiseButtons',
        'btford.socket-io',
        'ngMaterial',
        'BlurAdmin.filters',
        'BlurAdmin.directives',
        'BlurAdmin.theme',
        'BlurAdmin.pages',

    ]).config(routeConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin');
    }

})();

(function () {
    //Setting HTML5 Location Mode
    angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages').config(['$locationProvider', locationProvider]);

    function locationProvider($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true
        });
    }

    angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages').config(['$httpProvider',
        function($httpProvider) {
            // $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
            // delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }]);

    /*angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages').constant('configURL', {
        appName: window.location.host,
        appVersion: 2.0
    });*/



})();
```

and here is my `bower.json`

```
{
"name": "blur-admin",
"version": "1.2.0",
"homepage": "https://github.com/1itvinka/blur-admin",
"authors": [
    "akveo"
],
"description": "Blur Admin HTML template",
"license": "MIT",
"ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
],
"dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "~2.4.0",
    "Ionicons": "ionicons#~2.0.1",
    "amcharts": "~3.15.2",
    "amcharts-stock": "*",
    "ammap": "~3.14.5",
    "angular": "^1.6.6",
    "angular-material": "^1.0.7",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.8",
    "angular-slimscroll": "~1.1.5",
    "angular-smart-table": "~2.1.3",
    "angular-toastr": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-touch": "~1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "~0.15.0",
    "animate.css": "~3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-select": "~1.12.1",
    "bootstrap-switch": "~3.3.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "~0.7.1",
    "font-awesome": "fontawesome#~4.4.0",
    "fullcalendar": "~3.0.1",
    "highlight": "~8.8.0",
    "angular-socket-io": "^0.7.0",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.12.1",
    "jquery.easing": "~1.3.1",
    "jquery.easy-pie-chart": "~2.1.6",
    "leaflet": "~0.7.5",
    "moment": "~2.17.0",
    "slimScroll": "jquery-slimscroll#~1.3.6",
    "angular-progress-button-styles": "~0.1.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.3.2",
    "angular-chart.js": "~1.0.3",
    "angular-chartist.js": "~3.3.12",
    "chartist": "0.9.5",
    "angular-morris-chart": "~1.1.0",
    "ionrangeslider": "2.1.4",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.3.3",
    "angular-animate": "~1.6.6",
    "textAngular": "~1.4.6",
    "angular-xeditable": "~0.5.0",
    "ng-js-tree": "~0.0.7",
    "ngSweetAlert": "angular-sweetalert#^1.1.0",
    "json-formatter": "^0.6.0",
    "angular-promise-buttons": "^0.1.17",
    "angular-ui-scroll": "^1.6.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.6",
    "angular-ui-select": "^0.19.8",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "^1.2.2",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.7.1",
    "angular-segment-analytics": "^1.2.0",
    "angularjs-slider": "^4.0.2",
    "lightslider": "^1.1.5",
    "angular-confirm-modal": "^1.2.3",
    "ng-emoticons": "^2.1.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.0.4",
    "he": "^1.1.0",
    "MultipleDatePicker": "multiple-date-picker#^1.4.1"
},
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.6.6",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.2"
},
"overrides": {
    "amcharts": {
        "main": [
            "./dist/amcharts/amcharts.js",
            "./dist/amcharts/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js",
            "./dist/amcharts/serial.js",
            "./dist/amcharts/funnel.js",
            "./dist/amcharts/pie.js",
            "./dist/amcharts/gantt.js"
        ]
    },
    "amcharts-stock": {
        "main": "./dist/amcharts/amstock.js"
    },
    "ammap": {
        "main": [
            "./dist/ammap/ammap.js",
            "./dist/ammap/maps/js/worldLow.js"
        ]
    },
    "bootstrap": {
        "main": [
            "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "js/dropdown.js",
            "./dist/fonts/**.*"
        ]
    },
    "slimScroll": {
        "main": "./jquery.slimscroll.js"
    },
    "font-awesome": {
        "main": [
            "css/font-awesome.css",
            "fonts/FontAwesome.otf",
            "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot",
            "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg",
            "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
            "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff",
            "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

this my `foot.jade` where all my files are including.

```
      if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'quality')
.
.
.

        script(src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyATbh2hmRt6MN9bGC4PMAm9BDm7E4Lkj8A')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/dest/concat.min.js?v=' + process.env.querystring)
    else
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/crypto-js/crypto-js.js')

        script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/jstree/dist/jstree.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/ng-js-tree/dist/ngJsTree.js')
        script(type='text/javscript' , src='/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your HTML type should be
    type='text/javascript' 
not type='text/javscript'

Comment: Oh Em geeeeeeeeee